# How can I use an interactive function in a script?

Tags: init-file, interactive

I'm using **[virtualenvwrapper.el](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el)** to load Python virtualenvs during emacs sessions. I would like emacs to **start** with a default one, so I don't have to load it manually every time.

To load it manually, I use

> **M-x** venv-workon <kbd>RET</kbd>
>
> **Virtualenv to swich to:** myvirtualenv <kbd>RET</kbd>

How can I do this through `init.el`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interactive simply provides a way to call the function via M-x.  You can use `venv-workon` normally, like any other emacs-lisp function.  Here's an example:

```
 (require 'virtualenvwrapper)
 (venv-workon "my-python-project")
```

For more detail on what interactive does, see [Using Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html#Using-Interactive) from the Elisp docs.  Essentially, `interactive` marks a function as a command and defines how arguments passed to a command should be parsed.

Comment: It works perfectly for the shell. Now how can I assign it for [flycheck use](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/starting-a-virtualenv-for-emacs-to-use)?