# Starting a virtualenv for emacs to use

Tags: init-file, python, flycheck

I am starting a Python **virtualenv** through `init.el` (or so I would like):

```el
(require 'virtualenvwrapper)
(venv-workon "my-python-project")
```

However, **flycheck** does not find `flake8` or `pylint`, which are installed there. Starting emacs in a terminal with the virtualenv loaded works fine.

Is it possible to configure **init.el** to start a virtualenv for **flycheck** to use?

**EDIT**

Seems that this is related to an open [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1329217) in `python-mode.el`

Comment: Have you tried using elpy? It includes pyvenv which is able to switch virtualenvs automatically.

Comment: I don't think that the bug report is related.  You neither mention virtualenv.el nor python-mode in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason, today this works (without projectile or elpy):

```el
;;;; Syntax checking (Flycheck)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(setq flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(mode-enabled save new-line idle-change))

;; Default virtualenv (notice I didn't require virtualenvwrapper
;; python-environment or pyvenv prior to loading it. I have
;; all of them installed.)
(if (equal (getenv "VIRTUAL_ENV") nil)
    (venv-workon "my-python-project"))

;; Python autocompletion and doc browsing (Jedi, requires jedi and ipc
;; installed in the Python environment emacs is working in)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:setup-keys t)                      ; optional
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                 ; optional
```

I included the **flycheck** (first) and **jedi** (last) blocks because that is the closest thing to requiring anything remotely related to Python before I set the default virtual environment. I tested it starting emacs from a shell running no virtualenv (works); running the default virtualenv (works); and running a virtualenv without *jedi* installed (does not work). So I'm confident this is actually working as expected.

Comment: You can use `unless` to simplify your `if` expression, and you can remove the assignment to `flycheck-check-syntax-automatically`, since that's the default value anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a prebuilt way to do this.  I hacked around it like so.  This depends on having all of your virtualenvs in ~/.virtualenvs, and having projectile installed.

```
(defvar my:virtualenv-directory "~/.virtualenvs/"
  "The directory of virtualenvs.")

(defun my:configure-python-venv ()
  "Set `python-shell-virtualenv-path' to the virtualenv directory."
  (interactive)
  (require 'projectile)
  (let* ((project-name (projectile-project-name))
         (virtualenv-path
          (file-truename
           (concat my:virtualenv-directory project-name))))
    (when (file-directory-p virtualenv-path)
      (setq python-shell-virtualenv-path virtualenv-path))))

(defun my:flycheck-python-set-executables ()
  "Set flycheck python executables for the current virtualenv."
  (let ((exec-path (python-shell-calculate-exec-path)))
    (setq-local flycheck-python-pylint-executable (executable-find "pylint"))
    (setq-local flycheck-python-flake8-executable (executable-find "flake8"))))

(defun my:flycheck-python-setup ()
  "Setup flycheck for Python with virtualenvs. "
  ;; my:flycheck-python-set-executables uses buffer-local variables
  (add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook #'my:flycheck-python-set-executables
            nil 'local))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'my:configure-python-venv)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'my:flycheck-python-setup)
```

Comment: I changed your answer to explicitly set the local values of Flycheck variables for [forward compatibility](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/546).