# How to use a prompting interactive function in an elisp source file

Tags: file-local-variables

I've seen [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5457/how-can-i-use-an-interactive-function-in-a-script), but it doesn't work for this case.... Basically, I want to do a `load-file` on an .el file containing

```
(add-file-local-variable-prop-line "eval" "(set-input-method 'TeX)")
```

and have it add

```
;;-*- eval: (set-input-method 'TeX)  -*-
```

at the top of that same file; instead, it inserts

```
;; -*- "eval": "(set-input-method 'TeX)"; nil
-*-
```

which is mangled and doesn't work. Obviously, the double-quotes  (and the `nil` too?) render it bad. But then using no quotes and single quotes to satisfy the two interactive prompts produce errors. How can I do this non-interactively "batch" style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with interactive functions at all.

An interactive function is just a function where emacs has some metadata about how the arguments to the function are to be filled in when the function is called by the user. This metadata is ignored when the function is called from code instead. It's up to the caller in this case to supply the necessary arguments, same as for any function call.

In this case the important line is `(insert (format "; %S: %S; " variable value))`. This is how `modify-file-local-variable-prop-line` ultimately puts the text into the buffer. If we look at the help for the `format` function (`C-h f format RET`), we see that %S tells it to print the argument using `prin1`, which has the goal of reproducing the lisp value exactly. Thus, if you pass in a string as the variable, it'll be printed as a string so that when someone calls `read` on it they get back a string. This means that you want to pass in the `eval` atom rather than the string `"eval"`:

```
(add-file-local-variable-prop-line 'eval '(set-input-method 'TeX))
```